# How to turn my Ubuntu PC into a work-space for my other laptop?

Tags: ssh, workspaces, vnc

I have two laptops, one is my main laptop and the second acts like a server for my TV.

I control the server one with wireless mouse and keyboard for convenience. but i wish to improve that.

I really admire the workspace concept in Ubuntu and was wishing to embed the main screen of my server as a workspace in my main laptop

so when i want to do something i can easily just change work-spaces do what ever i want to do and change back.

i know i can do this with VNC but i think doing it as a work-space will be much smoother
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to work around this issue, i am not fully in control of the mouse but i gained much control on the keyboard inputs.

I used Ubuntu custom shortcuts ( Accessible by pressing super key then writing keyboards ) then i name my command and write the command it self which usually goes like this `ssh HOSTNAME '. .profile;command;'` and then i wrote command on my media center to be received which is mostly what i use like

```
xdotool getactivewindow key f
```

to go in full screen mode and such 
and i use ALT+{{Key}} as my short cut as ALT isnt used that much 
so i gain a lot of control on my media center.

Answer (score 2):

[Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) is a commercialized open source product which enables this, and there's a [Linux GUI for it](https://code.google.com/archive/p/quicksynergy/).  [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/blob/master/README.md) is an free fork of Synergy.

If that doesn't do what you want, then run a remote desktop app like VNC, full screen, in one of your workspaces. Here's a [list of such apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support); to filter on Linux only, double-click on Linux Client and Linux Server on the table's title bar.